# Deezer javascript authentication without pop up login

Tags: deezer

Id like to somehow be able to authenticate programatically using javascript, without filling a login form every time, because its unwanted behaviour in requirements for my app...

When I use Deezer javascript api I usually do:

```
    DZ.login(); //to login, which pops up a login form

    //then somewhere else calling

    DZ.getLoginStatus(function(){callback});

    //and in callback function I call the api or something
```

**What I would like to do might be something like this:**

- once call `DZ.login()`
- once fill in login form and approve rights for my app
- once get `access_token`(never expiring, with offline access permission) from response

Still good...
**and then:**

- somehow use that token from javascript everytime I need to access that account to do some action..

No matter whether Im logged in or not I want to be able to access that account with that offline `access_token`and

f.e. load my playlist to the player.. I want to do that action **everytime without prompting login form**, even after power failure or even if some earthquake comes and logs me out...

**I want to use javascript because of that player......**

1. **Is there any possible workaround?**
2. **If not, why is it not possible?**

Answer (score 0):

> No matter whether Im logged in or not I want to be able to access that account with that offline access_token and

What you want to do can be set up in your app settings as explained here: http://developers.deezer.com/api/permissions